# Measure Points to Coastal lines?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, saga, calculate-values, shape-area

I would like to measure the shortest distance from multiple points to a any part in a coast line of three different costs.
How do I do this with QGIS or with SAGA GIS?

Comment: In QGIS the tool to get distances between features in two layers - your points and coast lines - is called "Distance Matrix...", and you can find it from top menu under Vector / Analysis Tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the `Join attributes by nearest` algorithm in QGIS. It returns not only the join of attributes (which costline is the nearest) but also the distance between the input geometries (shortest line between points and lines/polygons). It also yields the X and Y coordinates of the nearest point on the coastline which could be used for visualizing the shortest line or calculating ellipsoid based distances.

Answer (score 0):

I now found the easiest solution for me to be the Qgis-Addon NNjoin.

Comment: Hi! GIS.SE is a little different than other help sites. Please post comments using the 'add a comment' button as soon as you have enough reputation and don't post it as answer. If you found the answer useful, you can accept it by clicking the green check symbol below the vote counter.